LaTeX command for repeating quotes n-times?
I'm trying to find a LaTeX command that allows me to repeat a specified character (like quotation marks) a certain number of times around a given text. For example, I want to define a command like \quote[n]{y}, which would output n repetitions of a character surrounding (the quotations marks in this case) the text y.
Is there a package with a command doing this job? If not, how could I define it?
Note that, in LaTeX, n repetitions of the quotations marks would have n times repetions of the left quotation mark (i.e., `) at the left and n repetion of the right quotation mark (i.e., ') at the right. Alternatively, it could be n repetions of the command \enquote{}, with suitable adaptations (each repetion should onctain only one pair of simple quotation marks).
OP edit:  Is there a way to, instead of puting ` at the left, to indicate the left quote of the command \enquote* provided by the csquotes package (and respectively for ')?  I say this because I would also like that it be adapted to other languages, like German.

Have a look at the pgffor package.

Also Expl3 has several loops for a defined functionality.

@elmo It is usually frowned upon to change a question after you've already got replies for the previous version of your question.

As egreg has posted an expl3 version here's a tex primitive loop, just for comparison

\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\lccode`~`m\lowercase{\endgroup
\def\Quoted#1#2{%
  $\mathcode`m="8000\def~{\hbox{`}}\romannumeral#1000$%
  #2%
  $\mathcode`m="8000\def~{\hbox{'}}\romannumeral#1000$%
}
}
\begin{document}

\Quoted{1}{abc}

\Quoted{2}{abc}

\Quoted{10}{abc}

\end{document}


Thans, @David Carlisle. Is there a way to, instead of puting ` at the left, to indicate the left quote of the command \enquote* provided by the csquotes package (and respectively for ')?

This reminds me of the “regular expression” that applies the sieve of Eratosthenes.

@elmo yes/no I avoided a specific loop by using math mode to give a magic definition for say mmm (which is roamn for 4000 but that rather limits what you coudl do, you could generate mmm and then loop over the m but then you may as well loop from 1 to 4 without the romannumeral trick which is what @egreg shows

@elmo yes just change the \hbox{\}to\UseName{csq@thequote@oopen}in this answer and you get whatcsquotes` would use.

@Skillmon oh I thought the OP needed to generate \enquote{\enquote{...{abc}}...}} which would be harder this way but OK yes if you just need left and right quotes separately, then as you say.

BTW. very neat trick using \romannumeral (though it limits the number of "iterations" to "only" 2147483).

@Skillmon David Kastrup I think

@Skillmon especially useful pre-etex to get expandable loop with no expandable version of \the\numexpr\foo+1

Well, you'd still need to loop over the ms with some auxiliary code for it to be expandable. But I think if you're fine with a maximum of 2 million iterations this is indeed faster than a \numexpr-based loop.

With expl3 there's \prg_replicate:nn.
We need to insert a zero kern in order to avoid ligatures.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Quoted}{O{1}m}
 {
  % #1 = number of quote marks (default 1), #2 = text to be quoted
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {`\kern0pt}
  #2
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {\kern0pt'}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Quoted{abc}

\Quoted[2]{abc}

\Quoted[10]{abc}

\end{document}


For csquotes:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Quoted}{O{1}m}
 {
  % #1 = number of quote marks (default 1), #2 = text to be quoted
  \group_begin: \setquotestyle{\languagename}
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {\use:c{csq@thequote@oopen}}
  #2
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {\use:c{csq@thequote@oclose}}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Quoted{abc}

\Quoted[2]{abc}

\Quoted[10]{abc}

\selectlanguage{french}

{\enquote*{abc}}

\Quoted{abc}

\Quoted[2]{abc}

\Quoted[10]{abc}

\end{document}



Thanks, @egreg. Is there a way to, instead of puting ` at the left, to indicate the left quote of the command \enquote* provided by the csquotes package (and respectively for ')?

@elmo See edit.

@egreg sorry, you were robbed

For the sake of variety, a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Note that because \Quoted uses Lua's own string.rep function, it's not necessary to perform a loop operation.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Quoted}[2][1]{\directlua{tex.sprint ( 
    string.rep ("\\mbox{`}",#1) .. "#2" .. string.rep ("\\mbox{'}",#1) 
    )}}

\begin{document}
\Quoted{abc}

\Quoted[2]{abc}

\Quoted[10]{abc}
\end{document}


Well, strictly speaking, David's answer doesn't involve a TeX-loop as well.

@Skillmon - Thanks. My comment was meant as a glosse on the OP's use of the loops tag. I guess I could have been a bit clearer... Thinking about the topic of loops, I suppose I don't really know how Lua implements the string.rep function -- might it involve executing a for loop?

It might :) (more characters)
